# Is it proper to use size_t for count in a bitshift operation?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, size-t

This small, seemingly insignificant question, occurred to me recently, but after googling quite a bit, I have been unable to find even an opinion on the subject. Only loops and object sizes are referred to.

I know people like examples, so here the one that cause the question in the first place:

```
uint64_t deltaSwap( const uint64_t b, const size_t delta, uint64_t mask )
{
    return b ^ mask ^ ( mask &=  b ^ b >> delta ) << delta;
}
```

I've been trying too optimize this for a while, knowing full well that this is not the way to write proper code, though it has given me the best result so far, at least with GCC, and then it occurred to me. If you really want to be pedantic, shouldn't delta be of type `size_t`?

I never really understood when to use `size_t`, so I never really do, but if I were to, wouldn't this be correct usage?

Update:
Here's the short explanation of what it does, although not how it does so, as I'm not really sure how to explain it:

It is a standard delta swap, which is not a new ideal, and the code works fine, this isn't really about the code (but since you asked), and all I've really done is experimenting with it, to achieve the best performance, and the version you see here, is my best result so far.

The purpose of the code is to swap two or more bits, fx if you wish to swap the first and the last bit, it could be done thusly:

```
deltaSwap(b, 63, 0x0000000000000001);
```

or if you wish to reverse the order of the bits:

```
deltaSwap(b, 32, 0x00000000ffffffff);
deltaSwap(b, 16, 0x0000ffff0000ffff);
deltaSwap(b,  8, 0x00ff00ff00ff00ff);
deltaSwap(b,  4, 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f);
deltaSwap(b,  2, 0x3333333333333333);
deltaSwap(b,  1, 0x5555555555555555);
```

though for this particular task, deltaswaps are probably not the best way to go.

Update 2:
Just for completion, this is the most correct onliner I can think of (haven gotten my answer), and the compiler apparently optimizes it perfectly.

```
uint64_t deltaSwap( const uint64_t b, const uint_fast8_t delta, const uint64_t mask )
{
    return b ^ ( mask & ( b ^ b >> delta ) ) ^ ( mask & ( b ^ b >> delta ) ) << delta;
}
```

I would've shortened the variable name to get it all to fit within the 80 character with imposed by my ocd brain (and apparently this site as well), but for you all, I'm willing to suffer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207909/discussion-on-question-by-zacariaz-is-it-proper-to-use-size-t-for-count-in-a-bit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you really want to be pedantic, shouldn't `delta` be of type `size_t`?

No, if you really want to be pedantic, `delta` should just be an unsigned integer type capable of holding *at least* the range of values from `0` to `sizeof(uint64_t) * CHAR_BIT`. In your case that's `[0, 63]`. There's no real need to have it be `size_t`.

> I never really understood when to use `size_t`, so I never really do, but if I were to, wouldn't this be correct usage?

In terms of correctness of code, it's ok. In terms of optimization it doesn't make much sense. `size_t` is used to hold a size, because it's a type guaranteed to be capable to hold the biggest possible size of an object. It's certainly *not* guaranteed to be any faster than a normal `unsigned` or any other unsigned integer type (see bottom of the answer for this).

Another important thing to notice is that this:

```
 b ^ mask ^ ( mask &=  b ^ b >> delta ) << delta
```

Is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) according to the C standard, since you are using the value of a variable while also applying a side effect to it in the same statement (see paragraph 6.5 point 2, page 76 [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).

The correct way to do what you want is:

```
mask &= b ^ (b >> delta);
return b ^ (mask ^ (mask << delta));
```

In any case always take extra care when working with bitshift operators since they have precedence over other bit operators. Using extra parentheses or splitting expressions into multiple lines doesn't hurt performance and improves readability. A decent compiler will optimize the above without any problem.

---

Now, back to the real reason you're asking this question: optimization.

The correct way to optimize your code is to *let the compiler choose* the optimal size of the variable that you need. For this purpose, you only need one byte, and you can use `uint_fast8_t` from `stdint.h`, which is the fastest (implementation defined) unsigned integer type with width of at least 8 bits. The compiler will choose the fastest width for its purpose.

With the above being said, the correct way to optimize your code is:

```
uint64_t deltaSwap( const uint64_t b, const uint_fast8_t delta, uint64_t mask )
{
    mask &= b ^ (b >> delta);
    return b ^ (mask ^ (mask << delta));
}
```

Depending on what you're doing it might as well make sense to declare the function as `inline __attribute__ ((always_inline))` if GCC does not already inline the code for you, though the compiler is usually better at figuring out when to inline code and when not. Your function is most probably already going to be inlined.

One more important thing: using the right optimization flags often matters more than hand-tuning code. For example, for the above code, you might want to compile with `-Ofast -march=native`, and maybe even other flags depending on where you use the function (e.g. `-ftree-vectorize` if used in a loop).

Other than the above: benchmarking, switching to hand-tuned assembly with an `asm()` statement and looking at the surrounding code are the only ways to optimize the above further, assuming that the formula is already simplified to its core.

Comment: `[0, 64]` is incorrect. It must be `[0, 64[` or `[0, 63]`. Shifting a 64 bit variable by 64 bit is undefined behavior. Shifting a 64 bit variable by 0 bits however is defined behavior.

Comment: *"I can only speculate that you wanted to do something like:"* - You do not need to speculate. The OP edited this already at revision 5, but was later rolled back to revision 4 by wildplasser.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio ah, totally missed that. Makes sense.

Comment: Am I to understand that had it been a normal assignment and not &=, then if would not have been undefined?
Also thanks for the hint on the compiler optimization. -march=native does in deed make a difference, though a small one.
I am aware of operator precedence, which is the reason for the missing parenthesis, as they're not needed. Again, this was not the version of the code intended for this question.
I'm unsure it inlining will actually work, but I had planned to look into it.
Again, thanks for the answer, uint_8fast_t it is.

Comment: *"Am I to understand that had it been a normal assignment and not &=, then if would not have been undefined?"* - no! That would still have been undefined behavior if done inside that expression, since you are modifying the value of the variable as well as using it a second time in the same statement (e.g. `x ^ (x = y)`). That's the definition of UB. And yeah I was not sure if the order of operations was correct seeing that strange assignment there in the mix.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli
so when people do something like:
if( !(myPtr = malloc(somesize)))

which happens quite a lot, that is undefined as well? I'm just asking because I've seen it so often, that it's frankly difficult to believe it is undefined.

Comment: @Zacariaz no, because in that case there is only one assignment and no other reference to the same variable in the expression. That's completely fine. The problem arises when using the same variable name twice in the same statement: one time with a side-effect and one time without a side effect. Classic examples of UB are: `i = i++;`, `x = a + a++;`, `x = a + (a = 2);`, `a[i++] = i;`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Ah, then I'm with you. I still don't agree that it should be undefined, but I'm perfectly able to accept that it could be.
I must say though that while all your examples make perfect sense, I don't really see any of them applying to my particular case.
In any case, I often think that these examples are not really all that confusing as people make them out to be.
fx. i = i++, what is the issue really? We usually don't assign anything before were done on the right side, thus 'i' should be incremented and then assigned it's original value.
In any case, important stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Marco, Disagree with "delta should be an unsigned integer type capable of holding at least the range of values from 0 to sizeof(uint64_t) * CHAR_BIT. ".  The best type to use would depend on use cases.

Comment: @Zacariaz "We usually don't assign anything before were done on the right side" --> It is not a _we_, but what the compiler could do.  The assignment and the increment could happen simultaneously and create a bus conflict - end of program.   Code to the standard rather than how one thinks a compiler may perform.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm not sure if I follow you, that sentence of mine only means that *the correct way of declaring delta* is using an unsigned type with enough bits to hold the needed values (which you could apply to virtually any context). I am not saying that it's "the best" there. That of course depends on the case.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica When did I claim anything different from what you're stating? I'm simply stating what makes sense, to my mind, and how I think it ought to be.
I for one would never do something like  i = i++, why would I? but if I were to do it, I would expect either compilation failure, or the behavior previously described, not undefined behavior.

Comment: @Zacariaz Welcome to C.  C compilers often assume when code might incur UB, the programmer knows what they are doing and so _allows_ it.  If you want a warning/error, then fully enable your warnings.  All good compilers detect this UB and report when fully enabled.

Comment: Sure technically speaking warnings are not errors, but they are most likely *symptoms* of errors. You should always treat warnings as errors. In case of `i = i++;` only a warning is emitted, but that code is without a doubt wrong.

Comment: @Zacariaz UB is not an error as defined by C.  If you want warnings to be treated as errors, enable that compile option as in gcc [-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html.)

Comment: UB does not necessarily generate any diagnostics; it's relatively recent that compilers have started to warn about `i = i++` and so on

Comment: @M.M if by "recent" you mean it's been 13 years then sure. GCC v4.1.2 (2007) warns `operation on 'i' may be undefined` with `-Wall`. That's also just the oldest GCC version I could test on, that kind of UB detection is probably there from earlier.

Answer (score 2):

`size_t` is an integer type that is guaranteed to be able to store the output of any `sizeof()` operation. This has a couple of implications: No block of coherent memory can have more bytes than `size_t` can represent as number. This also means that no array can have more elements than `size_t` can represent as a count. Also no C string can have more characters than `size_t` can represent as a length.

As for when to use `size_t`, you should always use it for storing memory sizes, array counts, array indices, and string lengths, as only this will lead to really portable C code. Using `int`, `long`, or `uintX_t` for that purpose may work on some platforms but can fail on other platforms. Note that even `malloc` expects an argument of type `size_t`, `printf` supports it as well using `%zu`, and most string operations in C use it as input/output for string lengths.

As for mixing integers of different width: Only `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, and `long long` (as well as their unsigned counterparts) are real native integers in C. The other integer types are just aliases to one of these native types added with later C standards. When mixing different types within a single operation, the smaller type is promoted to the larger one, unless both types are smaller than `int`, in which case they are both promoted to `int`, as C performs all operations on `int` or larger types, never on smaller ones:

```
char a = 1;
char b = 2;
char c = a + b;
// Last line is in fact: char c = (char)( (int)a + (int)b );

long l = 20;
long m = m * b;
// Last line is in fact: long m = l * (long)b;
```

So if you mix `uint64_t` and `size_t`, then either both become whatever type `uint64_t` is as a native type or they both become whatever type `size_t` is as a native type, whichever type is larger, unless both are smaller than `int`, in which case both become `int`.

Thus using `size_t` for a shift is perfectly okay, as any integer type can be used on either side of a shift operation.

Comment: Detail: "The other integer types are just typedefs to one of these native types." -->very very likely, yet could be another type.

Comment: UV "Thus using size_t for a shift is perfectly okay."

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You are right, they are not necessarily `typedef`s so I changed that sentence. In fact compilers can internally have a completely different type system and just map integer types to that system, even types as `int` can be mapped. Yet there is a reason why `(u)intX_t` types are all optional in the C standard whereas the fast/least types are not: It may not be possible to map (u)intX_t to a native type as no native type may have exactly X bits but it will always be possible to map a least/fast type to one of the native types that must be supported.

Answer (score 1):

From the [ISO/IEC 9899:1999](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section **6.5.7**

> If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than
>   or equal to the width of the promoted left operand,
>   the behavior is undefined.

It means that in your case the requirements for the `delta` are

```
0 <= delta < number of bits in the left operand
```

Comment: The question was *shouldn't delta be of type size_t?*. The answer is you can use `size_t` for `delta`. But if you have `size_t delta = 64` and `uint64_t x = 1`, then `x << delta` will be UB.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but... Well, it doesn't rally answer the question, does it? Or am I just being daft?
Yes, size_t ensures that a negative value cannot be passed to the function, and with a minimum width of 16 bit, it ensure that that it can hold any useful value, but is it correct usage, would it be more correct to use unsigned char|int|short|long|long long, uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t or uint64_t? In fact, the correct type, really, would probably be uint_fast8_t, if that is, size_t is not in fact the most appropriate choice.

Comment: Even with `uint_fast8_t`, you can get UB. In fact, the compiler will optimize anything you use to some number in the range [0, register_width]. You can try [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/oxBSzs) to play with it.

Comment: Yes, every type will potentially get OB, but since we don't have a 6 bit unsigned type at hand, the best we can do is ensure that it can hold what we need it to hold, and then potentially do at test for OB, which is not necessary in my case.

Comment: I personally use `size_t` for shift delta. Semantically, it is a number of bits, so I feel `size_t` just is more readable.

Comment: @Zacariaz "but since we don't have a 6 bit unsigned type at hand"  --> expect for field `unsigned f:6;`.